# React escaping vars inside an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  {emails.map(item => (
      <tr><td>{item.date}</td><td>{item.from}</td><td>{item.to}</td><td>{item.subject}</td><td><a href="{item.s3_key}">view</a></td></tr>
    ))}
```

I am trying to set the href="{item.s3_key}" but it just returns the string literal.
I can't see docs for this, can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using quotes on attribute or props value which contains variable value:

```
<a href={item.s3_key}>
```

And if you want to combine string then you may use like:

```
<a href={'view/'+item.s3_key}>
```

Or using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like:

```
<a href={`view/${item.s3_key}`}>
```

Comment: Note on the template literal example `backticks` are used and not 'single quotes'.

Answer (score 5):

With quotes around the `item.s3_key`, it will be parsed as a string. Remove it to get the desired result.

`href={item.s3_key}`

Comment: What about adjoining strings and vars E.G. `view/{item.s3_key}`

Comment: @David You can always use string template inside curly braces - `href={'view/${item.s3_key}'}` (just replace " ' " with a backtick)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove quotes from prop value:

```js
{emails.map(item => (
  <tr>
    <td>{item.date}</td><td>{item.from}</td>
    <td>{item.to}</td><td>{item.subject}</td>
    <td><a href={item.s3_key}>view</a></td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Or if you need to join some text value use es6 template literals:

```js
<a href={`any-additional-text-here${item.s3_key}or-here`}>
```